# Solving for matrix in multiplication of matrix by vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a specific problem I have been trying to solve for some time, and can't figure out how to even start on it. (this is not for homework)
The original problem states:

> Let **a** and **b** be 3D vectors. Find a 3x3 matrix **R** such that **Ra** is equal to the rejection of **a** onto **b**.

I know that the projection of **a** onto **b** is equal to

$a-\frac{(a\cdot b)}{b^2} b$

and thats basically as far as I get. I would try to divide both sides by a, but as far as I know, vector division is not possible, therefore wouldn't yield any results. I've also tried just writing out the multiplication for the first row, and trying to solve for $R_{11}$, $R_{12}$, and $R_{13}$, but that turns into a big mess really quickly that I don't think is meant to be solved.

I think there is supposed to be a relatively elegant way to solve this, but I can't see what that could be.

Comment: Please use `\mathbf` for boldface letters, say $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會, why is this important?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Using boldface for vectors isn't important, but it's a common practice to use MathJax for mathematical entitles on this site.  In the quote block, OP has typeset the vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ without Markdown, that's why I left my previous comment.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會, yep, I noticed that people sometimes make such edits.. They replace Markdown with MathJax. But I never understood why you'd replace a simpler, more readable and easier to edit version of text with a much more cumbersome one (given the end result is the same)..

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev MathJax enlarges the variable a bit, so it's a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy here is to manipulate the expression for the projection of $a$ onto $b$ into the form $(\text{some matrix})a$. Note that $a \cdot b$ can be written as $b^Ta$. Also, any scalar "commutes" with a vector, so $(b^Ta)b = bb^Ta$. Hence,

$$a-\dfrac{a \cdot b}{\|b\|^2}b = a - b\dfrac{b^Ta}{\|b\|^2} = Ia - \dfrac{bb^T}{\|b\|^2}a = \left(I - \dfrac{bb^T}{\|b\|^2}\right)a.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!